# assembly file extension, .s79, .s82, s90, .asm, .s, etc...what are their differences?

Tags: assembly

Just saw assembly extension as titled in a couple of platform, but just wodering how they are different. Thanks.

Answer (score 12):

`.sNN` is used by IAR Embedded Workbench up to version 4. The `NN` varies according to the processor:

```
.s12  NXP HCS12
.s18  Samsung SAM8
.s26  Renesas 78K
.s34  Renesas M16C/R8C
.s37  Renesas H8
.s43  TI MSP430
.s45  National CR16C
.s48  Renesas M32C
.s51  8051
.s53  Renesas R32C
.s66  Maxim MAXQ
.s68  NXP Coldfire
.s78  NXP S08
.s79  ARM
.s82  Atmel AVR32
.s85  Renesas V850
.s90  Atmel AVR
```

Source: https://www.iar.com/support/user-guides/#!?tab=userGuides

`.asm` is a common extension for assembly.

`.s` and `.S` are used for assembly language by the GNU tools.  The difference is that the `gcc` frontend applies the C preprocessor to files with extension `.S`, but not to files with extension `.s`.

Fun fact: The IAR assembler also accepts `.msa` (found while researching the above).

Comment: It's not just GNU tools; other Unixes use `.s` / `.S` the same way, which is *why* the GNU tools use them.  I'd go as far as saying `.S` is for hand-written asm source, `.s` is for compiler-generated.  Even if you don't *need* gcc to run your file through CPP before assembling, I'd recommend `.S` to indicate to other humans that it's hand-written.  Also, nothing like `gcc -S foo.c` or other tools like a disassembler with a default filename will clobber it.

Answer (score 0):

The file extension (if I understand you correctly) is just a convention whereby some mechanism can recognise the file.

For example .ASMis used by some to represent a source file written in some assembly language.

On windows .EXE is a convention for programs that can be executed. .Dll is an extension for code that can be executed by another executable.

As it stands by itself file extensions usually have no intrinsic meaning, but they do help people provide with naming standards and thus help other understand what they are for.

Comment: my understanding is that, for assembly file, one extension, e.g. .asm is good enough, just like exe/com for all executable files. why so many extensions for assembly that I would think there must be some reasons but I just don't reckon.

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed sometimes that the extensions used sometimes relate to the type of microprocessor the code is written for.  So if it was for an 8051 it might be .s51.  I sincerely doubt this is universal.  I'd bet that whoever makes the tools just chooses one extension at random.